# How can I execute shell commands containing pipe characters in Vim 8 for Windows?

Tags: vim

If I execute the ex command `%!perl -lpE "s/a|b/c/"` in Vim under Windows, a command line opens with the generated command

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /c (perl -lpE ^"s/a ^<C:\Users\Jo\AppData\Local\Temp\VIi83B6.tmp ^|b/c/^" ^>C:\Users\Jo\AppData\Local\Temp\VIo83B7.tmp 2^>^&1)
```

which inserts the input redirection incorrectly before the vertical bar character. How can I change this behavior to make my command run correctly?

Answer (score 0):

I opened an [issue](https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/1743) for this and was told that as a workaround, I could try not to use temp files: :set noshelltemp
This workaround worked well for me.